# Is it possible to apply two functions to a list in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I wanted to call a function I wrote as well as add the elements to a hash-map. I wanted to know how I could apply both of these functions to the same list.

For example, I have the following code for DFS Recursive code

```clj
(defn dfs-recur [maze curr-loc goal-loc parent]
  (;;Want to add elements of the following list to the parent map 
   ;; and call dfs-recur on them
    (def unvisited (filter #(not (contains? parent %)) (get-neighbors maze curr-loc)))
    maze)
```

If I was to implement it in python it would look something like this. The issue is, I don't understand how to do all 4 things inside the for loop at once in Clojure

```py
def dfs-recur(maze, curr-loc, goal-loc, parent):
    neighbors = get-neighbors(maze, curr-loc)
    for i in neighbors:
        if i in parent:
            break;
        parent[i] = curr-loc
        if i == goal-loc:
            break;
        parent = dfs-recur(maze, i, goal-loc, parent)
    return parent
```

Comment: Need more details.

Comment: That's … quite far from working code, and … still not clear at all what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `when` you can perform multiple actions without returning.

For example

```clj
(when condition
    (assoc {} key value)
    (recursive-func arg1 arg2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
(assoc {} your-key (your-func your-list))
```

Comment: This would work, but I want elements from the list to be keys in the map, but I also want to call my function on them

Comment: How about this: `(reduce (fn [acc item] (assoc acc item (your-function your-list))) {} your-list)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
(into {} (for [x your-list] [x (val-func x)])

=> (into {} (for [x [1 2 3]] [x (str x)]))
{1 "1", 2 "2", 3 "3"}
```

Or one with a function also for the key:

```
=> (into {} (for [x [1 2 3]] [(str x) (* x x)]))
{"1" 1, "2" 4, "3" 9}
```

Comment: I like the idea of a for loop, however, I'm unaware how to perform multiple actions in the same for-loop.